# "Heaven would be a drink" means?

Tags: meaning, expressions

Sounded like an exclamation, in a movie. It was used when some family members meet each other after a long while.

Comment: From what movie? It's not an expression I'm familiar with.

Comment: It's an equative sentence (`A Is B`), so turn it around: _A drink would be heaven!_ is a positive response to an invitation to have a drink.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The Children (2008) by Tom Shankland

Comment: The only example I could find was a passage from [I'll Remember April](https://books.google.com/books?id=wLdHAEj3TzYC&pg=PA200&lpg=PA200&dq=%22heaven+would+be+a+drink%22&source=bl&ots=lg5rfPAKab&sig=XfNKycJyfamZd38P2H0Lo8JStxQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjisKGytpfNAhVGXVIKHeZLB30Q6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=%22heaven%20would%20be%20a%20drink%22&f=false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Heaven** — [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/heaven)

> 3. *informal* A place, state, or experience of supreme bliss
>
> *"lying by the pool with a good book is my idea of heaven"*

*"Heaven would be a drink"* is just a fancy way of saying *"A drink would be like heaven"*. Like John Lawler said in the comments, it is an example of "equative sentence"

**Equative** — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equative)

> The term **equative** is used in linguistics to refer to constructions where two entities are equated with each other.
>
> For example, the sentence *Susan is our president*, equates two entities "Susan" and "our president".